# Not receiving the response of 400 using axios

Tags: laravel, axios

This code is from my controller,

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] = $request->user()->createToken('myApp')->plainTextToken;
        $success['name']  = $user->name;

        $response = [
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $success,
            'message' => 'User login successful',
        ];

        return response()->json($response, 200);
    } else {
        $response = [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'User login failed',
        ];

        return response()->json($response, 400);
    }
}
```

This is my axios method,

```
const login = async () => {
    await axios.post("/api/login", form).then((response) => {
        if (response.data.success) {
            console.log(response.data.message);
        } else {
            console.log(response.data.message);
        }
    });
};
```

Here in the controller if the condition is false I don't receive any response.If I remove the `400` from return `response()->json($response, 400);` It gives me a response with `200` code. I don't want it to happen since this is an error. Appreciate it if somebody can point me to the error. Thanks

Comment: I don't know why you want that. Response 200 is the success status of a request and 400 is a bad request. Why do you want 400?

Comment: I want to show this error to the user. This is the error message. But this response cannot be retrieved from axios since it is 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a `.catch()` here like this:

```
const login = async () => {
    await axios.post("/api/login", form)
        .then((response) => {
            // Handle API success logic here
            if (response.data.success) {
                console.log(response.data.message);
            } else {
                console.log(response.data.message);
            }
        
    })
    .catch(({message}) => {
        // Error response will always take you here
        console.log(message)
    })    
};
```

### UPDATE

from your controller send the response as 200 for both cases:

```
if($auth){
   $response = [
      'success' => true,
      'message' => 'User login success',
   ];
        
  return response()->json($response, 200);
} else {
  $response = [
       'success' => false,
       'message' => 'User login failed',
   ];
        
   return response()->json($response, 200);
}
```

and then make a call as:

```
const login = async () => {
    await axios.post("/api/login", form)
        .then((response) => {
            // Handle API success logic here
            if (response.data.success) {
                console.log(response.data.message);
            } else {
                console.log(response.data.message);
            }

    })
}
```

### UPDATE #2

in your else part of controller:

```
else {
        $response = [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'User login failed',
        ];

        return response($response["message"], 400);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this too but the response array is not retrieving Instead it console.logs this one, 
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (settle.js:17:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:7)

Comment: try now, with ```{message}```

Comment: It gives me the error message but this one, Request failed with status code 400. But I want the exact error message :(

Comment: Well, in that case you need to send the message as an exception from your Laravel backend. you can ```throw new \Exception('Message for exception');```

Comment: Can you update your answer and explain to me how to do that with my controller code above. Thanks

Comment: check the update now

Comment: I can do the same thing but bro I need to return it as an error not with a success code

Comment: can you update your question showing the auth logic, how are you authenticating?

Comment: Check I have updated my question

Comment: Try now, if that doesn't work we need to contact ```hecker```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I really need to contact hecker :(